# await method on TableResult is not working when job is submitted via Session Mode using Apache Flink Operator

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

await method on TableResult is not working when job is submitted via Session Mode using Apache Flink Operator by creating FlinkSessionJob resource in kubernetes. The same code is working when the job is deployed using the application mode. Here is the sample code snippet

```
TableResult insertQueryResult = tableEnv.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table");
insertQueryResult.await();
```

Can someone please help me in resolving the below error?

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: The Job Result cannot be fetched through the Job Client when in Web Submission.
```

What is the workaround to execute a fallback function after executeSql? Will there be any possibility of adding await functionality in future releases(in Session mode)?